# "copy as html" in Tmux

Tags: tmux, clipboard

I remember I used to had a "Copy as HTML" option in Tmux, but I can't seem to find information about it either in the settings or looking online. Does anyone know if it still exists for some Tmux version, or how to replicate it?

Comment: It appears you wanted to add more content to your question - which is good - but you've done so as if you were instead answering your question.  Please consider editing your question and adding the content there instead; and then delete this 'answer'.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your looking for tmux2html https://github.com/tweekmonster/tmux2html ?
Most Linux distros have it packaged.
For example on Gentoo its app-misc/tmux2html